# Multiple import into SVN repository

Tags: svn, import

is there any way how to do multiple imports into SVN repository? I.e. I want to import first file a/b/file1.txt and then file a/b/file2.txt. First import is OK, but second one throws "directory a already exists" error.

Is there any way how to accomplish this multiple import?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, there is no such thing as 'multiple import'. Second one you be an add and a commit / check-in not an import.

Note that [as the documentation mentioned](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.5/svn-book.html#svn.tour.importing.import) you still need to checkout:

> After importing data, note that the original tree is not under version control. To start working, you still need to svn checkout a fresh working copy of the tree.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that...I thought, that it would be neccessary to do checkout-add-commit.